# Ошибка MySql при попытке добавить данные в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть такой конфиг:

```
<?php  
$config = array(); // указываем, что переменная $config это массив  
$config['server'] = "localhost"; //сервер MySQL. Обычно это localhost  
$config['login'] ="speedx"; //пользователь MySQL  
$config['passw'] = "123admin123"; //пароль от пользователя MySQL  
$config['user_db'] = "speedx"; //название нашей БД  

$connect = mysql_connect($config['server'], $config['login'], $config['passw']) or die("Error!"); // подключаемся к MySQL или, в случаии ошибки, прекращаем выполнение кода 
mysql_select_db($config['user_db'], $connect) or die("Все печально:("); // выбираем БД  или, в случаии ошибки, прекращаем выполнение кода  
?>
```

При попытке передать запрос на добавление записей в таблицу, вылетают ошибки:

> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php on line 12`
>
> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php on line 12`
>
> `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php on line 13`
>
> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php on line 39`
>
> `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php on line 39`

Подскажите, где трабл искать? В чем проблема?

Сервер переустановил, толку нет... Для пользователя БД поставил все возможные привилегии, толку тоже нет...

Comment: А выборка SELECT нормально проходит?

Comment: Да, нормально. Ошибок нет.

Comment: @speednext, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: На какой ОС Вы это запускаете? Unix, Win? На хостинге или localhost?

Comment: На WIN XP пользуюсь виртуальным сервером TOP SERVER 2.1

Comment: Проверил на том же TopServer, все работпет! Ищите ошибку в имени(БД, Юзера), пароле!

Comment: А приведите файлик: `T:\home\virtual\prime\page_block\reg\reg.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У пользователя, именем которого вы подключаетесь, недостаточно привилегий для модификации набора данных функцией "mysql_query()". Об этом гласит ошибка:

> Warning: mysql_query()
> [function.mysql-query]: Access denied
> for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO) in
> T:homevirtualprimepage_blockregreg.php
> on line 12

На локалхосте можно создать привелегированного пользователя.

Comment: Так я и так все возможными привилегиями наградил пользователя speedx

Comment: Подскажите, как создать такого пользователя?

Comment: http://php-myadmin.ru/learning/instrument-pma.html   -  Manual

Comment: Может быть вы подключаетесь к localhost через php, а пользователь, которому дали все привилегии, создан для IP 127.0.0.1 ? Для mysql это будут разные пользователи.

Comment: Скорее всего (98%), тут просто неверные имя/пароль.

Comment: IP 127.0.0.1 ? - Это скорее всего!
Опыт есть, не большой конечно))
Имя и пароль верные! 100000000 раз проверял.

Comment: 127.0.0.0 localhost prime second - это у меня в файле HOSTS
А было 127.0.0.1 localhost prime second Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Зайдите в phpmyadmin и посмотрите, какой пользователя для какого host создан. У меня, например, так:

`User/Host/Password/Global Privilegies
root/localhost/****/ALL_PRIVILEGIES
root/127.0.0.1/****/ALL_PRIVILEGIES
php/localhost/****/ТОЛЬКО_ЧТЕНИЕ_И_МОДИФИКАЦИЯ_UPDATE_INSERT`

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте правильность указания имени бд и пользователя, и пароля.

Comment: Все верно, я копипастом пользовался))

Comment: @speednext тогда проверьте тот ли скрипт исполняется, потому как в ошибке написано другое имя пользователя

Comment: Скрипт исполняется тот. Я уже разобрался, это Винда тупит после вирусной атаки наверное.

Answer (score 1):

'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - это дефолтные значения MySQL.

Значит совершение запроса происходит БЕЗ указания имени пользователя и пароля.

Но непонятно как без ошибок проходит соединение с БД...

Попробуйте в mysql_query указывать идентификатор соединения с базой (`$connect`)

Или, возможно, соединение происходит через драйвер `ODBC` тогда нужно порыть в сторону его настроек.

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке явно написано, что подключение идет пользователем 'ODBC'@'localhost' и при этом еще и не используется пароль! Так о каком пользователе speedx тогда вообще речь?

Иногда кстати помогает вот такое, у меня косяк был подобный, только конфиг парсило из XML:

```
$host = (string) $config['host'];
```

Понимаю, выглядит, как говнокод, но пока я не сделал приведение типа у меня не соединялось ни с БД ни с SMTP.

Comment: Да нету у меня ни в операционной системе, ни в сервере пользователя 'ODBC'@'localhost'. Что это вобще за пользователь такой? Может он гдето есть, да я не зная где...?

Comment: Указан пароль и логин, соединение нормально проходит, ошибок нет. Это винде пипец после вирусов, с которыми не справился гавнокасперский, но за то справился AVAST! 7.0 Это не реклама!